# How assembly compilators know where to place functions?

Tags: python, assembly, compilation

How do assembly compilators know where to place labels/functions? 
I have been thinking about this problem and I couldn't find the answer.

Example code:

```
Func1:
    mov %ax, 0x100

jmp Func1
```

How does it know where to place it in good position in .bin/.o file?
Or it just jumps to end of the Function. 
I tried to create my own operation code just to make my emulator skip the function. But when it needs to be called it gets jumped to it with offset + 1 to skip the function operation code. \

To be clear, I'm making my own emulator and compilator to understand more how processors work. I can create simple compilators but at some point I must add jumps, conditional jumps and comparisons.

I create my emulator in python.

If anyone knows answer please answer. And I apologise for my bad english.

Comment: The job of placing compiled code at a particular address is the job of the linker. The linker will have a configuration to say where those places are.

Comment: Assembly is assembled, not compiled.  The tool to do so is called an *assembler.*

Comment: An assembler assembles source lines into bytes in the output at the current position (within this section).  Functions are a high-level concept you can *implement* in asm using labels and `call` /` ret` instructions, but the CPU and assembler don't have to know what functions are.  (Some asm syntaxes use `proc foo` / ... / `foo endp`.)

Comment: The assembler will place instructions & give labels values in the order they appear in the source or input text, (except that it collects and groups code together in a [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) and data together in a [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)).  If the assembler did differently programs would not work, as programmers and compilers generating assembly have an expectation of linear correspondence of the machine code to the assembly text.